# How to find who deleted data from my table in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have some table in my table which is accessible to many. Some data is missing in my table now. How can I find who deleted those rows from that table.

Comment: have you taken a backup of the database? if not then there are third party tools which can help you otherwise its difficult. try http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx

Comment: @Sushil Mate We don't have any backup of the database. I have the data in other test environments. Nut I want to find the culprit who deleted it without my acknowledgement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find deleted data's UserName by following little snippet :

```
DECLARE @TableName sysname
SET @TableName = 'dbo.t1_new'   --INPUT TABLE NAME

SELECT
    u.[name] AS UserName
    , l.[Begin Time] AS TransactionStartTime
FROM
    fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) l
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        [Transaction ID]
    FROM 
        fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) 
    WHERE
        AllocUnitName LIKE @TableName + '%'
    AND
        Operation = 'LOP_DELETE_ROWS'
    ) deletes
ON  deletes.[Transaction ID] = l.[Transaction ID]
INNER JOIN
    sysusers u
ON  u.[sid] = l.[Transaction SID]
```

source : dba.stackexchange
(I don't recall who posted it)

Answer (score 2):

You can use ApexSQL Log to fully investigate operations executed against your table. The database needs to be in the full recovery model, so the information on past operations is available inside the transaction log file for ApexSQL Log to read it. Once the tool analyzes your t-log, you will be able to see the time the operation began and ended, the operation type, the schema and object name of the object affected, the name of the user who executed the operation, and more. For UPDATEs, you’ll even be able to see the old and the new value of the updated fields.

There are several guides on this here https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/apexsql-log-solutions-table-of-contents/

Furthermore, you can even use ApexSQL Log to rollback those transactions if you need to. It will simply 'Undo' them and rollback changes back to their original state.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't see deleted records if you don't keep them somewhere yourself.

If you want to track this type of interventions, you should not really delete your records. 
Instead, you should create a some more fields on your table. 
Here is an exemple :

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person](
[Pers_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Pers_CompanyID] [int] NULL,
[Pers_FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Pers_LastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Pers_CreatedBy] [int] NULL,
[Pers_CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
[Pers_UpdatedBy] [int] NULL,
[Pers_UpdatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
[Pers_Deleted] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Pers_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =     OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

When the user creates a record, you can set CreatedBy = UserID, CreatedDate = CurrentDate,

While updating a record, UpdatedBy = UserID, UpdatedDate = CurrentDate

And deleting, Deleted = True, UpdatedBy = UserID, UpdatedDate = CurrentDate.

And in your code, in all queries you should add the condition Deleted = null.

Thus, you can track who created, updated or deleted a record.